# Will supervisor change the program master process

Tags: gunicorn, supervisord

Supervisor version: 3.3.3

I use supervisor to manage gunicorn processes.It works very well, but recently when I send hub to supervisor to reload gunicorn, gunicorn logs show me occasionally that

```
[2018-07-03 16:16:49 +0000] [25949] [INFO] Handling signal: hup
[2018-07-03 16:16:49 +0000] [25949] [INFO] Hang up: Master
[2018-07-03 16:16:52 +0000] [18459] [INFO] Parent changed, shutting down: <Worker 18459>
[2018-07-03 16:16:52 +0000] [18459] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18459)
[2018-07-03 16:17:00 +0000] [18458] [INFO] Parent changed, shutting down: <Worker 18458>
[2018-07-03 16:17:00 +0000] [18458] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18458)
[2018-07-03 16:17:00 +0000] [18456] [INFO] Parent changed, shutting down: <Worker 18456>
[2018-07-03 16:17:00 +0000] [18456] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18456)
[2018-07-03 16:17:00 +0000] [18455] [INFO] Parent changed, shutting down: <Worker 18455>
[2018-07-03 16:17:00 +0000] [18455] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18455)
[2018-07-03 16:17:00 +0000] [18457] [INFO] Parent changed, shutting down: <Worker 18457>
```

I have no idea to handle this situation.

Is that supervisor changed the gunicorn master process?

and how can I deal with this situation?

Comment: how is this a python question, and how is it a programming question actually?

Comment: I remove the `python` tag